# Async pipe in Angular 6, how to store object in components variable without subscribe()

Tags: html, angular, typescript, observable

consider following code snippet where I subscribe an Observable using async pipe in a components template:

```
<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let s of data | async">
    <td>some informations</td>
    <button (click)="setObject(s)">Save Object s in components variable</button>
  </tr>
</table>
```

My question is if there is a way to store the object retrieved from *ngFor in a components local variable? I know there is a way to store it in a templates variable, but I want to save it in a components variable.
So for example, if I click a button, a components setter method is called to store the object in a components variable of same type.

Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: Any issue you are facing with above code?

Answer (score 1):

You should create a component member and assign the `s` to it:

```
export class BlaBlComponent {
  clickedObject;
}
```

and do this in your template:

```
<button (click)="clickedObject = s">Click</button>
```

This will store the `s` reference to the `clickedObject` member on your component. This is quite basic angular stuff, and I advise you to thoroughly do the tutorials and read the documentation at [angular.io](https://angular.io). Or maybe I'm not getting the nature of your question

Answer (score 1):

here is example

```
<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let s of (data | async) as dt">
    <td>some informations</td>
    <button (click)="setObject(dt)">Save Object s in components variable</button>
  </tr>
</table>
```

also   [stackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7amv3q) link here